# xpath to element with attribute and grandparent attribute

Tags: c#, xpath

The relevant chunk of my xml is this:

```
[... lots of xml up here, including ancestor elements...]
<category id="MyCatID" ... >
   <option ... >
      <property id="MyPropID">The magic value I need</property>
[... lots of xml down here...]
```

My objective: Find the value of a `<property>` with `id` of `MyPropID` whose parent is `<option>` and whose grandparent (through `<option>`) is `<category>` containing the `id` of `MyCatID`.

Here is my attempted xpath:

```
//property[@id='MyPropID']/ancestor::category[@id='MyCatID']
```

In my .NET 4.7.2 that xpath query brings back all the xml inside the `<category>` element, which misses the mark. My hoped-for result is that it would bring back the value `The magic value I need`.

How is it done?

Comment: Why not reverse it, get the category with the ID you want and then navigate to the property with the ID you want? I'm not really sure how your XML looks, here's my pseudo attempt... `//category[@id='MyCatID']/option/property[@id='MyPropID']`

Comment: quaabaam: perfect! Can you post this as an answer, for the benefit of others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not reverse it, get the category with the ID you want and then navigate to the property with the ID you want? I'm not really sure how your XML looks, here's my pseudo attempt...

```
//category[@id='MyCatID']/option/property[@id='MyPropID']
```

Answer (score 1):

And if for some reason you would really want to do it bottom-up way:

> //property[@id='MyPropID']/../../../property[@id='MyPropID']

or

> //property[@id='MyPropID']/ancestor::node()[3]/property[@id='MyPropID']